# Drupal 7 PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

The query inserting data to the table breaking the coding flow.

**How to get rid of this exception:**

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'annual_spend'
```

Code:

```
INSERT INTO {mc_reward_accelarators} (`nid`,`reward_type_id`,`reward_level`,          `percentage_spend`,`accelerator`,`annual_spend`,`inc_bonus_perce`,`first_year`,`language`) VALUES ('25','0','0','0','HP','','','0','en'),('25','0','0','0','FP','','','','en');
```

Comment: Managed to solve I had to omit single quotes for int values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
INSERT INTO {mc_reward_accelarators} 
(
    `nid`,
    `reward_type_id`,
    `reward_level`,
    `percentage_spend`,
    `accelerator`,
    `annual_spend`,
    `inc_bonus_perce`,
    `first_year`,
    `language`
) 
VALUES 
(
    25,0,0,0,HP,,,0,en
),
(
    25,0,0,0,FP,,,,en
);
```

Avoid using (') in values.